# MATLAB GUI loaded image glitch when drawing axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a GUI in MATLAB that loads an image of the program acronym (source ref.: Link 1).
[image]
[Link Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsBno.png)

At a later step in the program,
I draw the following plot in a separate panel (source ref.: Link 2).
[image]
[Link Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyTBN.png)

When it draws the plot axes,
the color from the plot is also drawn
on the original image
(source ref.: Link 3).
[image]
[Link Fig.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeXTk.png)

**I have tried so far:**

- changing the image format
- placing the image on another separate panel
- changing properties of the axes

Any suggestions on how to stop this from happening without having to redraw the logo each time? Any guesses as to what is causing this to happen?

**SOLVED**
converted to truecolor image like Jens Boldsen suggested.

Comment: wild guess: what about using `drawnow` after creating the plot/displaying the images?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It actually already calls drawnow because the plot is in a series of loops.

Comment: It may be because you are using indexed image for the first image, try converting the first image to a true color image.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: PhillyAI, either you or @JensBoldsen should write this up as an answer so you can accept it. Adding `[SOLVED]` in the title really doesn't do anything.